# how to connect to mysql using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using the below code to connect mysql using SQLAlchemy, help me out with the proper code. My configuration as below:

```
username: root
password: ''
host: localhost
port: 3307
db: logdb
```

MySQL was configured as:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/login'
```

code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/logdb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

def __init__(self, username, email):
    self.username = username
    self.email = email

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % self.username

admin = User('root', 'admin')

db.create_all() # In case user table doesn't exists already. Else remove it.

db.session.add(admin)

db.session.commit() # This is needed to write the changes to database

User.query.all()

User.query.filter_by(username='root').first()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install `pymysql` first.

```
pip install pymysql
```

and then config your mysql as :

```
mysql+pymysql://root:password@127.0.0.1/logdb
```

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: Make sure you have started your MySQL and also confirmed that use default port

Comment: DB details: (host='localhost',port=33067,user='root', password=' ', db='Securityr')

Comment: i have stated mysql server

Comment: @RanjithN just modified it to 33067